# ASP.NET Core Web API DELETE Call Returns 405

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, http-status-code-405

MY asp.net core web api is returning a 405 when I try a DELETE call. When the API is running in my local machine I can send the delete call successfully.

In IIS under the site's Handler Mappings WEbDAV has DELETE listed as one of the verbs to be handled:
[IIS WebDAV settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0MRD.png)

web.config has DELETE listed as a specified verb as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ServiceCatalog.API.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The delete endpoint works when testing from my local computer but once deployed I get the 405 return message.

In case it helps here is the code for the DELETE endpoint in the API

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public ActionResult DeleteImage(int id)
        {
            Images img = new Images();
            img.Imageid = id;

            //Check that the recrod exists to be deleted. IF not return NotFound status
            var imgCheck = _context.Images.Any(i => i.Imageid == img.Imageid);
            if (!imgCheck)
            {
                return NotFound("No record found to delete.");
            }

            //delete selected image record
            _context.Remove(img);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            // Return the id of the deleted record   
            return Ok("Image Id " + img.Imageid + " has been successfully deleted.");         

        }
```

Code for the ConfigureServices of the API

```
// Cors Configuration
            services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy,
                    builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://xxxweb011",
                                 "http://xxxweb011.x.com")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
            });

            
            services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
            });


            // Connection string from environmental variables
            var connectionString = Configuration["connectionString:101stg"];
            // Connection to SQL
            services.AddDbContext<ServiceCatalogContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


            services.AddControllers()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJson();


            services.AddOData();

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Code for Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            /*
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
                {
                    appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected fault happened. Try again later.");
                    });
                });
            
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
            */
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();    //Keeping always shown during development

            app.UseRouting();


            //added for screenshot uplaod
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
                endpoints.Select()
                            .OrderBy()
                            .Filter()
                            .SkipToken()
                            .MaxTop(100)
                            .Expand()
                            .Count();
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
            });
 
            app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            
        }
```

Comment: How are you making the Delete call? postman or some front end client?

Comment: I tested using both Postman and my web front end. When I point them at my local machine when running the API delete call works. It is when I try against the published API I get the 405. Cannot find what on the sever is stopping the DELETE verb.

Comment: so other verbs are working? Can you check iis logs?

Comment: Yes the GET, POST, and PATCH verbs are all working with no issues.
I will go check the IIS logs.

Comment: I also added my code from the API if that helps with the troubleshooting.

Comment: IIS log shows:
2020-09-24 11:06:19 172.27.108.84 DELETE /analyticscatalogap/api/41 - 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx PostmanRuntime/7.26.5 - 405 0 0 390

In this case 41 is the id of the record to be deleted.

I have tried each proposed solution when it comes to WebDAV settings on the server with no luck.

Comment: If I remove all verbs from the WebDAV Request Permissions setting the API no longer accepts my previously working requests such as GET which is expected. When I update the list of verbs to the following: GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE  they all work with the exception of DELETE which still returns a 405 error.

Comment: So it's reaching iis logs, can you check your middleware in ConfigureServices method. And try some response to return.

Comment: I added the ConfigureServices code to the post. What do you recommend I try to change?

Comment: My apology, it should be `configure` method, can you please provide that code.

Comment: Added the code for the configure method.

Comment: `app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
  await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Request.AbsolutePath);

            await next();
        });/*
            if (env.IsDevelopment())`

Comment: Can you try that, you will be knowing if the request is flowing through your middleware

Comment: I still get the 405 error. Still appears to be something from IIS that is not sending my request to the api.

Comment: which .net core version? May be you can check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: asp.net core 3.1

Comment: If your other verbs are working so hosting in IIS has no issues. May be the call has issue. So from your any get method can you call with delete, then you will no if it's verb issue or routing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to disable/modify all the WebDAV settings in IIS that I could find the only solution for me ended up being to comment out the following line of code in the applicationHost.config file

```
<add name="WebDAVModule" />
```

To be safe I also commented out the following line as well

```
<add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```